# Inventory System for Computers and Devices for the IT Department

Tags: hardware, inventory

I am looking for a computer hardware inventory system that have the following general criteria:

- Cheap / Free / Open source - It makes things easier to get approved.
- Can track the different devices we have around the office: Desktops, laptops, mobile devices, monitors, etc.
- Reporting functionality.
- History

Just for an idea of scale, we only have around 300 employees.

I seen other inventory systems that looks like it can do what I need but doesn't specialize in handling computers (if that even matters). Just would like some recommendations for software that is actually used in the IT industry.

Answer (score 1):

[10-Strike Network Inventory Explorer](https://www.10-strike.com/networkinventoryexplorer/) is a fine tool for this (runs on Windows).

The tool can
- scan your network and find all the available devices over LAN.
- store the information on hardware and software installed.
- monitor changes and notify you about that.
- create reports on any information scanned (100+ built-in reports and the Report Designer function are available).